# C-FFI for JavaScriptCore/React-Native

Tags: react-native, javascriptcore

Dart has an FFI that allows to lookup plain C-functions from libraries and call them directly and also allows to pass pointers to Dart functions to C-functions for callbacks.

That way it’s quite easy to use C-libraries from Flutter.

Does React-Native allow through JavaScriptCore to do something similar: Directly call plain C-functions?